# Combining Polygons from matching features into a single MultiPolygon feature with QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, geoprocessing, geometry-conversion

I have a GeoJSON file from an upstream provider that uses multiple feature "rows" to represent disjoint boundaries of what I need to treat as a single feature.

For example in the dataset that can be previewed at https://data.cityofchicago.org/Education/Chicago-Public-Schools-High-School-Attendance-Boun/8vea-73uh and downloaded at https://data.cityofchicago.org/Education/Chicago-Public-Schools-High-School-Attendance-Boun/is3f-j4ke you can see that "HIRSCH HS" (to pick one such case) has **three** attribute rows all with `school_id` of `609712` linked to three **separate** polygons for its boundary.

[image: Screenshot of linked website, with multiple "Hirsch HS" popups open on its preview map]

I want to gather all "matching" features — in this case whenever the `school_id` column has the same value — and merge the geometries of each such group into one feature. Is this possible do (in a semi-automated fashion) using the QGIS user interface?

[And yes in this example it looks like technically each row is *already* a "multipolygon" but regardless I want to aggregate duplicate attribute rows together into one *single* multipolygon so that I have only one unique feature for each underlying row ID.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make one polygon separated by `school_id`, right?

Use the `dissolve` tool in QGIS.
It can be found in the `Vector` menu -> `Geoprocessing Tools` -> `Dissolve`.

Just select the `school_id` as the dissolve field.

If you only want to work with features with duplicate `school_id`, use the `select by expression` to select them.
The condition is `COUNT(1, "school_id")>1`.

Comment: Yes, I want to make one MultiPolygon per *unique* `school_id` if that's what you mean by "one polygon separated". So I might have 15 polygons in the input file, but only 10 actual schools, and I want to join all polygons **only if they share** the same identifier value. So I get one multipolygon **per school** → i.e. 10 features out. I'm guessing that's what the "dissolve field" is for then and will try it out soon, thanks!

Comment: Confirmed, yes! The QGIS tool does exactly what I wanted with the "dissolve field". The dissolve tool creates a new layer, looking at the field I choose to keep separate features unless the value matches.